# bundle install fails with "failed to build native extension"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]

When I try to run `bundle install` I get the following output:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........  
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..  
Resolving dependencies...  
Using rake (10.1.1)  
Using i18n (0.6.9)  
Using minitest (4.7.5)  
Using multi_json (1.8.4)  

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.  

    /Users/jchirag/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb   
creating Makefile  

make  
compiling atomic_reference.c  
atomic_reference.c:53:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  
    if (OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64(expect_value, new_value, &DATA_PTR(self))) {  
        ^  
1 warning generated.  
linking shared-object atomic_reference.bundle   

make install  
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 atomic_reference.bundle ./.gem.20140205-2120-t32ean  
Script: on: No such file or directory  
Script started, output file is started  

Script done, output file is started  
/usr/bin/install: line 2: script:: command not found  
Script: on: No such file or directory  
Script started, output file is done  

Script done, output file is done  
make: *** [install-so] Error 15  


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jchirag/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection.  
Results logged to /Users/jchirag/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out  
An error occurred while installing atomic (1.1.14), and Bundler cannot continue.  
Make sure that `gem install atomic -v '1.1.14'` succeeds before bundling.  






when I try to run gem install atomic -v '1.1.14' I get the following:  

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...  
ERROR:  Error installing atomic:  
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.  

    /Users/jchirag/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb  
creating Makefile  

make  
compiling atomic_reference.c  
atomic_reference.c:53:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  
    if (OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64(expect_value, new_value, &DATA_PTR(self))) {  
        ^
1 warning generated.  
linking shared-object atomic_reference.bundle  

make install  
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 atomic_reference.bundle ./.gem.20140205-2359-wp4uhi  
Script: on: No such file or directory  
Script started, output file is started  

Script done, output file is started  
/usr/bin/install: line 2: script:: command not found  
Script: on: No such file or directory  
Script started, output file is done  

Script done, output file is done  
make: *** [install-so] Error 15  


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jchirag/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection.  
Results logged to /Users/jchirag/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out  
s
```

I have already executed `sudo gem update --system`
I am using mac osx 10.8.5, I have already updated my xcode to latest.

Any clues will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For similar problem I just run the following and follow the prompts

```
 xcode-select --install
```

Comment: running this gives me:

xcode-select: Error: unknown command option '--install'.